# javascript - dynamically create results pages for each table entry

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an app that contains results for some tests.
The results are kept in a cloud DB. I need to create a page for each entry in this DB that will show the specific results of the current entry. The template is the same for each entry, just need to change the data in it every time.

How can I do something like that?
Thanks very much,
Tal

Comment: do you have any piece of code which you have tried?

Comment: Too broad my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to duplicate your pages,
you should use a templating engine with express (https://expressjs.com/) to manage your routes.

Example :

```
    // app.js --> running on your server
    app.set('view engine', "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ENGINE"); // jade, pug, twig ...

    // index here corresponds to your index. html file
    app.get("/one", (req, res) => {
      res.render("index", { message: 'Hello there 1 !'});
    });
    app.get("/two", (req, res) => {
      res.render("index", { message: "Hello there 2 !"});
    });
```